# Creating image pop-up from uploaded database field

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to create a pop-up to show images which have been uploaded into my database.

I have tried

```
echo '<td><a class=help  href="'.$dbRow['image'].'"></td></tr>';
```

the class represents the pop-up class

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript"> 
$('.help').popupWindow({ height:400, width:500, top:100, left:100 });
 </SCRIPT>
```

Any suggestions how I get the image to display from the database as a pop-up? The image field is retrieving on my webpage from the database but need it to click as a pop-up to display

Comment: how is the database irrelevant when thats where the image is being retrieved from in the first place!!

Answer (score 0):

Use [jQuery](http://jqueryui.com/) for this.

Use an loop to echo all images to the certain div.

```
<div class="help">
<?php
  foreach($key as $value) {
       echo '<a class="help"  href="'.$value.'"><br/>';
  }
?> 
</div>
```

then display the dialog

```
<script>
$('.help').dialog({
    //your dialog options here
    height:'500',
    width:'500',
});
</script>
```

See [jQuery dialog](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/) for more info about the dialogs

Comment: thanks. should i still include echo '<td><a class=help  href="'.$dbRow['image'].'"></td></tr>';

Comment: im receiving a syntax error on line  while($key as $value) {

Comment: sorry, my bad. the while has to be an foreach. see updated answer

Comment: its not showing up. does $value represent my $image?

Comment: please check [php foreach](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: If this answer helped you, please 'accept' this answer, you can do that by clicking the check mark next to the vote buttons.